# UWP : writing a huge log file is very slow

Tags: c#, uwp

I try to write a log file and it's huge amount of data. I use AppendTextAsync every time I want to add data to create the structure I want and it's very slow. Is there any way to improve it?

```
        await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, "All event log messages   \r\n");
```

Comment: Don't await it immediately? Whats the point of calling it asynchronously to then wait for it?

Comment: I need to await otherwise the execution of the method continues before the call is completed.

Comment: What you have is pretty much equivalent to `FileIO.AppendText(file, "All event log messages   \r\n");`.

Comment: but in FileIO there's no AppendText. it's only AppendTextAsync

Comment: Are you collecting log step by step or it is just one big dump?

Comment: I am collecting it step by step

Answer (score 2):

`AppendTextAsync` will open the file, seek to the end, write to the file, close the file.  This involves a lot of work for the OS, especially for writing a single line of text.

Open the file once, append all the text required, then close it.

Answer (score 0):

As somebody else mentioned `AppendTextAsync` open and write and close the file every time so I changed it to this:

```
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
            using (var outputStream = stream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {

                using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outputStream))
                {


                    dataWriter.WriteString("All event log messages   \r\n");
                    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();

                }
            }
            stream.Dispose();
```